# IIS7 not having access to web.config

Tags: iis

I have published a .net 4.0 web app. I am trying to configure IIS7 to show my app and I created a new application pool with .net framework 4.0 configuration.

Then, I created a new app and pointed to the virtual directory. I went to the URL and I see a blank page. Trying to configure default pages resulted on an error:

[image: IIS Error]

I think I am having a permission error on the virtual directory. I gave full control to users IUSR and "Everyone" but nothing changed. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot request web.config files from your browser.  If you are having trouble viewing the file using something like notepad or sublimetext let us know.  Again, web.config files are hidden from browser requests, and will cause a server error if requested.